# If cell[2,5] is not cell[5,5] in pandas (not value but cell)

Tags: python, pandas, cells, xlrd

I am using Pandas and I am turning an excel spreadsheet into a dataframe and am trying to do the following:

```
if RowCol[2,5] is not RowCol[5,5]: 
    calculation
```

Right now my data frame is called z and I have the following:

```
if z.iloc[2,5] != z.iloc[5,5]: 
    calculation
```

However this does not work because it takes the value of the row,col into consideration. If row,col 2,5 is 10 and row,col 5,5 is 10 then the calculation won't run, when in fact I want it to run. The only time I don't want the calculation to run is when the row, col is 5,5.

I know that I can get the values using iloc but I don't care about the values, I just want it so that if we are not on row,col [5,5] then the calculation runs but if we hit row, col [5,5] in the dataframe then the calculation does not run but a different calculation is run only for row,col [5,5]. Does anyone know what function to use for this, I don't think I use loc?

Comment: are you iterating over the frame, or are you just comparing two values? Your last paragraph indicates that you just want to iterate over the frame and avoid [5, 5], but then why do you check [2, 5] at all?

Comment: I am iterating over every row,col in the dataframe. I need to do a calculation when I am not on cell [5,5] but when I am on cell [5,5] I need to do a different calculation. I need to iterate over all cells including [5,5]

Comment: so if you're iterating have you tried just having an external counter just keep track of the current position you're on

Comment: I know that I can do that, but I was wondering if there was a specific function like iloc or something of that nature for this?

Comment: Did you explicitly define an index array when you defined a dataframe or can we assume it's using [0, 1, 2,..]

Comment: It is using 0,1,2,....

Comment: Sounds like twisted logic. Take a step back and describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that since you are iterating over the dataframe already it would be better to just keep track of your current position. `df.iterrows()` keeps track of your index.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    rownum = 1
    for cell in row:
        if index==5 and rownum==5:
           do_stuff()
        rownum+=1
```

Comment: thanks yeah I just ended up keeping track of it, couldn't find a function that did it

Answer (score 0):

Because you only care about the row (seems you are fixed on column 5)

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    if row == 5:
        continue
    else:
        myfunction()
```

If you don't want to loop you can do

```
inds = range(len(df))
inds.remove(5)
df_not5 = df_not5.ix[ df.index[inds],  ]
```

and hen calculate on the subdataframe